# Triggering event in C#.NET Form by tabbing into field

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms

I am designing a form using C#.NET. Whenever a user selects a text field to fill out an event triggers that shows a picture corresponding to the field they are filling out. However, some users like to use the tab key to move through the form. When tabbing through the text fields, the event is not triggered and the picture does not show up. I need to know how to get .NET to trigger an event when a user uses the tab key to move into a field.

Comment: well, how are you triggering events currently?  If you used the `OnFocus` (or `GotFocus`, whichever it is) that would probably solve your problem.

Comment: Which event are you using at the moment?

Comment: Right now I'm using textbox.isClicked

Comment: You want `Textbox_Enter` event   or `TextBox_GotFocus`  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter(v=vs.110).aspx  for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any event with the word "Click" in it will generally only be fired by a mouse action which is why it is not being fired by the user using the tab key.

The `Enter` or `GotFocus` event will be fired by both the mouse and the keyboard when the cursor enters the control.  Just create the `_Enter` event for your textbox and move your code into it.

If you want to remove the image when the textbox loses the cursor just use the `_Leave` event.